# Problem with subcaption package - undefined command

Tags: captions, document-classes, subcaption, undefined

I am currently writing my own document class (which is very inspired by the book class) and I am facing a problem when using the `caption` and `subcaption` packages.

Here's a part of my class*emphasized text*:

```
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}

\newcounter{figure}

\newenvironment{figure}{%
    \@float{figure}%
}
{\end@float}

\renewcommand\thefigure{%
    \@arabic\c@figure%
}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{%
    \arabic{subfigure}%
}

\newcommand\figurename{Fig}

\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{1}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{format}{\textbf{\textsc{#1.~#2. -- }}}

\captionsetup[figure]{
    name={Fig},
    labelsep=none,
    labelformat=format,
    textformat=simple,
    justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=true,
    font=footnotesize,
    textfont=it,
    position=bottom,
}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{
    name={Fig},
    labelsep=none,
    labelformat=format,
    textformat=simple,
    justification=justified,
    singlelinecheck=true,
    font=footnotesize,
    textfont=it,
    position=bottom,
}
```

For the simple figures, no problem, everything goes perfectly well. But when I try to insert subfigures I get the following error concerning the document class:

```
Command \thesubfigure undefined
```

Do you know where this mistake came from? I've read the documentation of both packages but I'm not very advanced. . .

This is the first time I write my own document class, it's quite different from a "classical" use of LaTeX, so please excuse me if my class is a makeshift job. Thanks

PS : Here is link for the document class : [MyClass.cls](http://dl.free.fr/en5fErhjX)

The figure environment is defined on lines 382 to 410 and the caption on lines 452 to 510.

And here is the link for .tex file : [Test.tex](http://dl.free.fr/gLoCwSwbi)

Comment: Move `\newcounter{figure}` before `\RequirePackage{subcaption}` or manually use `\DeclareCaptionSubType[*]{figure}` (see doc of `subcaption`, sec. 5). When loading `subcaption`, `\DeclareCaptionSubType` is called automatically for `figure` and `table`, if the corresponding counters are defined.

Comment: Hello @muzimuzhiZ, thank you for your help, however, even doing so, the error message persists... :/

Comment: It seems you are defining a new document class from scratch. Can you provide a complete example, containing the contents of both `.cls` and `.tex` files?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Yes indeed I made this class from scratch to be able to fully customize it and better understand how LaTeX works. Be careful, my class document is still in work, so it is not very "clean" and it contains a lot of comments in French.

Answer (score 2):

- When loading `subcaption`, it automatically calls `\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}` if counter `figure` is defined.
- Inside `\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}`,

  - command `\ext@figure` is expanded. (Actually this happens inside the expansion of `\caption@@@@declaresublistentry`, defined in `caption3.sty`)
  - new counter `subfigure` is defined, hence the corresponding command `\thesubfigure` is defined.

For counter `table`, similar things happen.

So the key is to provide counter `<float type>` and command `\ext@<float type>` before calling `\DeclareCaptionSubType[*]{<float type>}`.

A full example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcounter{figure}
\newcounter{table}

\makeatletter
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\ext@table {lot}
\makeatother

\RequirePackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{...}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable} {...}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```